# Where should beginners start when using Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, new-users

I've read about Stack Overflow for a long time on *[Joel on Software](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/)*, but I am new to Stack Overflow. And I am not good at English (I am a Chinese). I signed up yesterday, so I can feel every corner of Stack Overflow.

After logging in, I tried to click these "vote" buttons but was reminded, I must have 15 reputations but I only have one. I don't know why.

I have read the **FAQ** for a while, but I can't find the information I need. For example, can I search for an answer in a specific question if I want to answer it? Because this question has a lot of answers (more than 400), I don't want to read every answer below this question and also I don't know if what I know has been added already.

Does Stack Overflow want to internationalize these **FAQ** and **Help** documents? If Stack Overflow has this plan, I can give a hand on the Simple Chinese edition.

PS: Why can't I create new tags while I ask a question if my reputation is less than 500?

Comment: Be aware, that the FAQ also include this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faq

Comment: Thanks, this link is a good place for me to learn more about StackOverflow. // When I use other web apps, they all provide a **help link** to tell users how to use there functions, so I just put my eyes on the **global faq** in the menu bar, who can know that he/she can get help or answers with tag "faq", especially the novices.

Answer (score 2):

Re the PS: because *in the overwhelming majority of cases*, the tag will already exist. You can always ask someone to re-tag it - we're pretty friendly. Most tags created by brand new users *tend* to be either over-specific ("foobar-1.2.4-on-Symbian-134") or just not follow the normal site conventions. Once you've been around the site for a little while you will probably have a much better idea of what makes a good tag. And what doesn't.

Re how to get started: either ask a question that you need answering (preferably with enough detail that it *can* be answered), or answer something that you know. Most pages offer a range of views, "newest", "unanswered", etc.

Comment: Thanks to Marc G and the person who vote my questions, I have got some reputations and gained some privileges, I feel very happy and have more understanding about StackOverflow. But I still think its hard to novices to use this web app. Without trust of Joel Spolsky, I think I wouldn't stay here anymore. Just as my another question say, if there is a place for novices to learn to use StackOverflow for fun, a lot of people will love this app soon :)