# New user can't vote

Tags: feature-request, new-users, privileges

I spent 10 minutes trying to get my Google or Facebook account to link, so I could login and upvote a useful answer, only to find that I need to have a reputation of 15 or more in order to do so.

It seems a waste of time to bother signing up at this point. And I'm sorry to the answer provider that didn't get my vote.

To be honest, for someone looking for a quick answer and trying to give a quick upvote, this site is not very intuitive.

No need for a reply, just giving feedback.

Comment: The reason for this is because we can't tell apart legitimate users who want to upvote vs. cheaters who create new accounts to upvote themselves.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the [privilege system](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges) is mentioned in the about page you see when signing up for the first time... Did you pass through the [about page](http://stackoverflow.com/about)?

Comment: Should you by now wonder "why on earth do I get downvoted for some feedback?", don't worry. You have tagged this as a feature request, seemingly to remove new user restrictions. And downvotes on Meta are sometimes used [to indicate disagreement](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences). That's all.

Comment: Consider how different your post is to http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/170459/grateful-frequent-user-not-allowed-to-express-gratitude, which was posted only 40 minutes before yours.

Comment: accepting an answer provides more rep to the answerer than an upvote, and it also as a (slight) increase to your rep too.

Answer (score 12):

Yes, you do need a minimum amount of reputation to vote. And for a good reason. We don't like cheaters. Hold on, I'm not referring to you. I'm referring to users who would otherwise quickly create accounts with the sole purpose to upvote their own content. And yes, this is a real issue. Reputation is part of the game, and any game will have cheats. So unfortunately, we do need to have minimal boundaries in place.

> Seems a waste of time to bother signing up at this point, and sorry to the answer provider that didn't get my vote.

Yes, it's unfortunate that you went through the process of signing up, only to find you could not do what you signed up for. But welcome to the site though! Why not participate now you have an account anyway. The required amount of rep is easily gained, and we always like to have new users and great contributions.

As for the answer not getting an upvote, don't worry too much. Answers are not only of value to you. Good answers are of value to the community as a whole. And if the answer was really good, the user will still get a fair amount of reputation for it.

> To be honest - for someone looking for a quick answer and trying to give a quick plus vote, this site is not very intuitive.

That might certainly be the case. The site does however provide a nice introduction to the basic concepts on [the new About page](https://stackoverflow.com/about). Check it out.

I know you said no need for a reply, but here you have one. Welcome to the site, and I hope you stay with us. And if you do ultimately gain the privileges, pay it forward. ;)