# Duplicates right after the Original post

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

Recently I noticed that there was a duplicate of [Grateful, frequent user not allowed to express gratitude?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/170459/grateful-frequent-user-not-allowed-to-express-gratitude), made less than three hours after the OP. While I believe that most duplicates on here are mistakes, I'm having a bit of trouble believing that a duplicate could be posted so quickly afterwards, especially from a new user (as was the duplicate poster in this case). Is there some special penalty for duplicates that appear to be spam, and should questions like these be flagged for deletion?

Comment: That's an extremely common "question", so it's not really unusual to see two in one day. There's probably dozens of duplicates, two in one day is just a bit much to ignore

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've seen similar questions asked within the same time frame before, so while it is odd timing, it is not terribly unusual.

To your point, what motivation, other than not knowing how to search, would someone have to post such a [poorly worded and poorly approached duplicate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/170474/new-user-cant-vote) when such a [great question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/170459/grateful-frequent-user-not-allowed-to-express-gratitude) was asked 64 minutes before?

I don't think anything special needs done to deal with these types of questions.  Just vote or flag as a duplicate of the earlier question and let it get closed and/or deleted as the matter of normal clean up efforts.

Also, your usage of the word *spam* is not accurate.  It clearly isn't spam since it is not advertising anything, just a very low quality post.