# Reputation - The cliff that you're trapped at the bottom of

Tags: discussion, support, stack-overflow, reputation

So I feel like this site (Stack Overflow) almost doesn't want people to be able to give people thanks for posting up questions or even giving thanks for people answering your own question.

When ever I go to do something I never have the rep. People down vote your questions like they're on youtube and or they expect everyone to be genius - if they were why would we be asking questions in the first place?

I can't comment on other peoples posts thanking them for their great question and answer, I can't up vote them for a good question. I can't do anything other then check the correct answer to my question. Which of the past two have both received down votes negating the point of even asking a question in the first place.

15 rep to up vote good quality answers and questions
50 rep to even do any commenting outside a question you post

I haven't tried to answer anyone's questions but I have to assume based on not being able to do anything in general that I wouldn't even be able to do that to get these rep standings.

***So what I'm getting at is how does one achieve these seemingly simple rep numbers when one is trapped in the chicken or the egg ?***

Comment: You can earn rep by improving posts. Edit posts that need substantial improvment and you will get 2 rep for every post approved. Also you did not give any answers yet. Questions normally don't get you much rep. And BTW these limitations are spam preventation.

Comment: Other duplicate posts: [How do you get more than 1 reputation?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/198240/187824), [How does a new user begin using Stack Overflow/Stack Exchange?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/188611/187824)

Comment: Oh i understand that they are spam protection, its just fustrating. For example user one posts something that is good but not exsactly what you wanted and user two posts something that is good but not exactly what you wanted. You could take them both combine them into what you wanted and post that answer. Wrong because you need rep to answer your own questions. 
Ok so then edit your answer and give the two candidates an up vote, which is also wrong as you can't up vote till your 15.

Comment: Ok so lets post questions which give you +2 when you accept a answer. This is counter balanced by people just down voting what they think to be a simple question that a kindergarten student could program.

Comment: It's not always easy, but if you stay at it and continue to improve, your rep will follow. You've been on the site for 26 days. Take your time, and give it some time.

Comment: To those already negative posting me, thanks for proving my point. Yes it is a possible re-post of other questions, because I can't comment on there or do anything. Till posting here of course, at least in meta.

Comment: The common response to the age-old "it takes a genius to ask a question" is "it does not take a genius to research the topic you're asking about". Nobody has ever said that it takes a genius to ask a question. Yes, it's really easy to ask a bad question, but that does not automatically mean it's so difficult to ask a not-so-bad question that you may as well give up trying.

Comment: You don't need any reputation to answer questions or your own questions.

Comment: [Voting is different on meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta)

Comment: Thanks Bart, I understand this, though one would think there would be a much simpler way through human checks to keep the spammers away. Requiring your questions and answers to solve a quick puzzle every so often. This would entice new users / wouldn't turn off potential answer's.

Comment: Questions about simple tasks don't get downvoted if you did your research and put effort in your question.

Comment: @hims056 I tried it on both questions asked and it says you need 50 to answer your own questions

Comment: Thank you all for the incite, just new user frustration level's I suppose.

Comment: @Darkn3ssF4lls - See [this help page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). If you have less than 100 reputation, you have to wait for at least 8 hours after posting a question for self answer.

Comment: @Darkn3ssF4lls Having reviewed your questions I'd suggest 1) reading, and practicing, [this](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx) 2) Not writing out an autobiography in each question 3) not editing your questions radically to reflect new problems or include the solution within the question 4) Find a mentor or teacher - seems you have the mind for it but are at an experience level that impedes communication. See my profile for my Twitter and hit me up there if you want to know more. Best of luck.

Comment: Take a deep breath, Read the **whole** help center and make sure you ask proper questions. Even if you are not a *genius*, if your question fits the standards, you will have a nice feedback.

Comment: @juergend actually, because of bikeshedding(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parkinson's_law_of_triviality) the simple tasks often get over upvoted.

Comment: @CarlVeazey, aye that's a good site definitely hits a few negative things I've done just out of an attempt to dis wade the auto down voting. To #4 Would enjoy that actually but I don't yes twitter.

Comment: Does anyone know how to get the question asking ability back?

Comment: There's a million questions in meta about it, hit me up on twitter if u have questions would be willing to help.

Comment: I don't have twitter

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> When ever I go to do something I never have the rep.

The primary activities on the site, asking and answering, don't need any rep

> I can't comment on other peoples posts thanking them for their great question and answer

You're not supposed to, comments are for requesting clarification and other things that lead to the eventual improvement of the post.

> So what i'm getting at is how does one achieve these seemingly simple rep numbers when one is trapped in the chicken or the egg ?

Also, how will posting comments get you rep? You say there is a chicken and egg problem. I see none. The two activities that are the easiest ways of getting rep, asking and answering, don't have any rep barriers. True, some questions are unclear and you may need to be able to comment to request clarification, but this is not true for most posts. Everyone else (of all rep levels) gains rep the same way.

If you're not getting upvotes on your questions/answers, I suggest you put more effort into them. Read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)/[How to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer) and the relevant pages in [the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) for tips on how to do this.

Comment: I didn't say commenting on peoples things would get me rep, i said rep is required to do these things outside of a question asked by you. This is the purpose of up votes of course, yet one cannot up vote without rep.

Comment: @Darkn3ssF4lls Yes, but for the lack of comments to be a part of a chicken and egg problem, it needs to be a source of rep. Which it isn't.

Comment: I can see what your saying, its not a source of rep. It is a rep restricted item though.

Comment: @Darkn3ssF4lls rep is there for those who are willing to work for it.  There are over [600,000 questions without a single answer](http://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/?tab=noanswers).  Some might not be answerable, but many are.  And the beauty is you don't need to know the answer.  Look for a question that sounds interesting in topics you enjoy and then do the research yourself and learn how to do it.

Comment: That sounds good to me Psubsee, never thought about pulling out the cold cases.

Comment: @Darkn3ssF4lls - There's even [a badge](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/837/revival) [or two](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/17/necromancer) for providing good answers to old questions.